# NSURLConnection response returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm using the following code to get a JSON response but the response returned is nil even though the data length printed is 256

```
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"method\":\"cargo_shipped\",\"data\":{\"username\":\"%@\",\"shipment_no\":\"70088000071790\"}}",username];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url..."]];
NSLog(@"url %@",request);
NSData *postData = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSLog(@"above loop");
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     NSLog(@"ENTERED url loop");

     if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"entered if loop");
         [self receivedCargoShippedData:data];
         NSString* cargoShippedResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         NSData *jsonDatas = [cargoShippedResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         NSDictionary *jsonDics = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonDatas options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
         NSLog(@"Request %@",bodyString);
         NSLog(@"Response %@",jsonDics);
        NSLog(@"result: %lu ",  (unsigned long)[data length]);

     }

     else if ([data length] == 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         [self emptyReply];
         NSLog(@"empty %@",connectionError);
     }
     else if (connectionError != nil && connectionError.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut)
     {
         [self timedOut];
         NSLog(@"empty %@",connectionError);
     }

     else if (connectionError != nil)
     {
         [self downloadError:connectionError];
         NSLog(@"empty %@",connectionError);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"%@",@"wtf");
     }
 }];
NSLog(@"finished");
```

}

The code enters the if loop and even the length of the response is 256. But still, when I try to get the response, its nil.

Comment: Why don't you post the code relevant to your problem?  I don't see anything about NSURLConnection here.

Comment: What about using `error` parameter of `JSONObjectWithData: options:error:`? Also are you sure that it's a NSDictionary at top level? What's the value of `cargoShippedResponse`? Why do you to NSData => NSString => NSData ? `data` and `jsonDatas` should be the same.$

Comment: I have posted my updated code

Comment: What's the value of `cargoShippedResponse`?

Comment: What's the value of `data` then?

Comment: Thank you, i have solved it and i have posted the working code

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself:

```
if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"entered if loop");
    [self receivedCargoShippedData:data];
    NSString* forgotPasswordResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Request %@",bodyString);
    NSLog(@"Response %@",forgotPasswordResponse);
}
```

Comment: FYI "if loop" isn't a thing.